# Inconsistent exception - Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium webdriver Ruby script and facing this error inconsistently:-

```
[remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:7610:in `fxdriver.cache.getElementAt': Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked
 up (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/AKULKA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20140510-2952-10nsq50/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7210:
in `Utils.getElementAt'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/AKULKA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20140510-2952-10nsq50/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8223:
in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible'
        from [remote server] file:///C:/Users/AKULKA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20140510-2952-10nsq50/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10861
```

Sometimes the script runs successfully and sometimes it throws this error and fails. 
I tried adding wait etc. but nothing helps.

What could be wrong?

Following is the code where the script fails: -

```
# Go to Maintenance tab
wait.until {browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a")}
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a").click
```

Its not just this line of code but sometime the script fails at another line throwing same exception and sometimes everything works perfectly.
Why such inconsistency?

Thank you in advance.
Abhishek

Comment: Write the source to a file before your search it. Get a copy of the source when your script fails and when it succeeds. Then run a diff on the two files.  Looking at your xpath, it is obvious your solution is very brittle.

Comment: @7stud"Write the source to a file before your search it" how should I do this? Also, theres no change in script when it fails or succeeds. Its same all the time.

Comment: Can you give some more context about what your script is doing? What are you doing before trying to click the maintenance tab?

Comment: Script is trying to click different JavaScript tabs within a module. Sometimes, the tab click is successful and sometimes it just does not proceed throwing element not found in cache error.